# Access Asset Type for subfolder

Tags: assets, matrix

I want to create asset subfolders by page & by asset type.
I use an asset field in an matrix field for multiple asset types like video, images etc.

In an asset field I can access the slug of an entry by:

```
{owner.slug}
```

Is there a way to access a an asset field inside an matrix block to fetch the kind for the asset subfolder? Like

```
{asset.kind}/{owner.slug}
```

To create an subfolder like

```
images/about-us/asset.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Assets field on your block has a handle of `asset`, you could do:

```twig
{object.asset.one().kind}/{owner.slug}
```

Comment: I already tried this approch:
The Asset field’s Default Asset Location setting has an invalid subpath (“{object.asset.one().kind}/{owner.slug}”).

Comment: This works. What's the handle of your Assets field?